# can't get Publisher ID from http://www.admob.com

Tags: iphone, ads, admob

I downloaded `Admob Iphone SDK` for building ads.
I read the Readme file. It told me to get Publisher ID from http://www.admob.com.

But I am **not able** to find **Publisher ID**  in my account on this website.

Where can I find it?

Comment: I would go to their support pages

Comment: This is not programming related. You should visit Admob's website for technical support with their product.

Answer (score 21):

The above answer is out of date.

1) Click "Sites & Apps" Tab
2) on your app click "Manage settings"
3) Below your app's app's name, and URL, you'll see "Publisher ID"

Answer (score 4):

Seems they have changed controls again.

Click on Sites & Apps.

On the page, locate your app name and move the mouse over it. The row will highlight and 2 buttons come up below the name of the app - Reporting and Manage Settings.

Click on Manage settings. Right under the app name on the top, you'll see the site URL and Publisher ID. That is what you are looking for.

PS - PublisherID is the same as adUnitID.

Answer (score 2):

Once logged in, go to Sites & Apps section.  After that, click on Tools link next to your app name.  In the app information, you'll clearly see Publisher ID.